# Cant retrieve Image from SQL Server In Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

i have a database that has field name of the following and also within the same table it also a field name "photo" and has a data type Varbinary(max)

i have no trouble in storing images but when i tried to display the image file from my database it doesnt display anything and i get an error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'."

```
Sub fillDataFields()
    Dim mid As String
    Dim last As String
    Dim first As String
    con.Open()
    comm.CommandText = "Select last_name,middle_name,first_name,course, section, address, birthday, picture from Users where user_id like '%" & frmUsers.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text & "%'"
    comm.Connection = con
    Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(comm.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
    If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
            ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
            PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
        End Using
    End If
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader
    While (dr.Read())
        last = (dr("last_name"))
        mid = (dr("middle_name"))
        first = (dr("first_name"))
        txtCourse.Text = (dr("course"))
        txtSection.Text = (dr("section"))
        richtxtAddress.Text = (dr("address"))
        txtBirthday.Text = (dr("birthday"))
        txtName.Text = last + ", " + first + " " + mid
    End While

    con.Close()
    dr.Close()
    comm.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Quick note, inline SQL is bad.  It's very vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  Consider using parameterized SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You try to extract the image data using [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but this method returns the first column of the first row and, in your query, this data is the content of the field `Last_Name`. This is the cause of the error

Said that, I suppose that you should apply your logic to the content of the field Picture

```
Sub fillDataFields()
    Dim mid As String
    Dim last As String
    Dim first As String

    con.Open()
    comm.CommandText = "Select last_name,middle_name,first_name,course, section, address, " & _
                       "birthday, picture from Users where user_id like @uid"
    comm.Connection = con
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", "%" & frmUsers.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text & "%")
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader
    While (dr.Read())
        last = (dr("last_name"))
        mid = (dr("middle_name"))
        first = (dr("first_name"))
        txtCourse.Text = (dr("course"))
        txtSection.Text = (dr("section"))
        richtxtAddress.Text = (dr("address"))
        txtBirthday.Text = (dr("birthday"))
        txtName.Text = last + ", " + first + " " + mid

        Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("picture"), Byte())
        If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
            Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
               ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
               PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
           End Using
        End If
    End While
    con.Close()
    dr.Close()
    comm.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Notice that I have also removed the string concatenation because it is a security rìsk (Sql Injection). You should also revise this code to apply the required logic for the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Comment: i applied your codes but now im getting an error that says.. "Out of Memory"

Comment: Difficult to say from here, what is the value of imageData.Length? Could you try with a different image?

Comment: i dont know what is the value of imageData.length

Comment: i think i know now what my error is? i think the file format is too large for the memory to handle.. 

i save the image in rawformat like in jpeg format.. do you know how will i convert it into smaller format ?

Comment: sorry my bad.. i tried to use a different file format.. but still is say its out of memory..

Comment: No I don't know. I suggest to post a new question with this specific new problem.